# Is is it possible to track the active file in the Solution Explorer that comes with the C# Dev Kit extension for VS Code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code

I can see that VS Code can track (auto reveal) the active file in the File Explorer. However the same doesn't happen in the newly introduced (through the C# Dev Kit plugin) Solution Explorer. I can't seem to find an option to activate that behavior... I know this is possible in regular Visual Studio for Windows but can Visual Studio Code do the same?

Comment: @starball yes. For example, if I go to the definition of a class, the file (where the class is defined) will be automatically selected in the Solution Explorer. In other words, the selected file in the Solution Explorer will be the file whose contents are being shown in the editor tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature has been implemented and will be in the March 2024 release of the dotnettools extension, at which point you can enable it using the `dotnet.automaticallySyncWithActiveItem` setting. The related issue ticket is [Track Active item in Solution Explorer view #51](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/51).

There's also a related feature-request for a command to do it (not automatically tracking): [[SUGGESTION] Reveal Active File in Solution Explorer (C# Dev Kit) #180](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/180).

For your reference / learning purposes, I found the above issue tickets by googling "`github vscode issues c# solution explorer auto reveal`".